# emacs python pdb hang

Tags: python, windows, emacs

I have successfully used 
    `M-x pdb` 
and then type in 
    `python -m pdb myscript.py` 
and step thru my code before when i have a linux box. Now i have to do all my work in windows. I have downloaded Vincent Goulet's emacs window disbribution and Anaconda2 Python distribution and while all the python shell is working the same M-x pdb step thru my code is not working. 
Precisely what happen is that i put in

```
M-x pdb
```

Then ask `Run pdb (like this):` 
I try all 3

1) `python -m pdb my_script.py`

2) `python my_script.py`

3) `my_script.py`

i get a new buffer `*gud-my_script.py*`
in it is
Current directory is `c:/User/my_user_name/Documents/python`
then it just hang there.

I also try other pdb use case (i.e in script my_script2.py, i wrote) 
    `import pdb; print "hello world1"; pdb.set_trace(); print "line 2"`

then just in emacs window command promot run 
    `python my_script2.py`
the command promot will not even shows "hello world1" and just freeze there and command prompt won't return

the strange thing is that if i run this NOT in emacs and just in windows command CMD then it will work. i.e. it will print "hello world1" and then drop into debugger.

i did not making any special entry in .emacs after i downloaded Anaconda so to be honestly i don't even know which python mode i am in and why emacs is preventing interaction to show up from pdb.set_trace()

there is similar problem in stack exchange. except i am not doing google app development. Mine is a minimum example. 
[emacs pdb just hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542504/emacs-methods-for-debugging-python)

Comment: I find a way to drop into debugger via emacs. 1) Launch the python shell (aka interpreter) 2) import pdb 3) then do pdb.run(my_script.my_func()) then i can step thru that function. And if that function has pdb.set_trace() inside then simply running my_script.my_func() will stop at that point and drop me into debugger. So functionally i can do my work, it still bug me a bit that the 'normal' methods cited in the main question did not work though.